# Problem validating if the user is logged in or not in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to check if the user is logged in or is logged in but I get a problem on my cell phone but I don't get a problem on the emulator.

If the user is logged in and exits the application, he should return to the main menu screen and if he is not logged in he simply goes to the login screen.

If I am running the app on the cell phone and it is connected to the computer, it works correctly (it correctly validates whether it is logged in or not), but if I disconnect the cable from the cell phone and do the login process again, exit the app and try to log in again , it does not work. It stays on the login screen.

In the emulator it happens to me practically the same, if I use the app but clicking on run in the android studio does not validate and it does not show me the correct screen when it is logged in or not.

CheckLoginUusuario this method will validate if the user has been logged in or not.
MainMenu is the other screen.

```dart
 class Frm_Login extends State<frm_Login>{
     bool islogin;
     Future<void> CheckLoginUusuario() async {
            SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
             islogin = prefs.getBool("CheckEstadoLogin");
      }

      @override
      void initState() {
        CheckLoginUusuario();
        super.initState();
      }

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return islogin == true ? MenuPrincipal():
       Scaffold(// login page
          child: new TextButton(
                 onPressed: (){ 
       
      if(KeyFormValidaciones.currentState.validate()){                              validarLoginservices.ValidarLogin(Contrasena.text,Usuario.text , context);  }
       },
       child: new Text("Login",style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 25,color: Colors.white),),
         )
        );   
        }
        
class ValidarLoginServices {
   SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
        
    Future ValidateLogin(ContrasenaLogin,CorreoLogin,BuildContext context) async {
         if(// if validate password and email is ok ){
      await prefs.setBool("CheckEstadoLogin", true);
     Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>MenuPrincipal()), (route) => false);
        }
}}
```

Comment: Please use conventional capitalizations.  Your code is confusing otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though you are calling `CheckLoginUusuario` inside initState, it will take some frame to get data from sharedPreference.

You can call setState to rebuild the UI once data has been fetched.

```dart
 Future<void> CheckLoginUusuario() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = awaitSharedPreferences.getInstance();
    islogin = prefs.getBool("CheckEstadoLogin");
    setState((){});
  }
```

A better practice is using FutureBuilder.

Comment: What do I do in the set state? return screens depends on the state? Could you give me an example?

Comment: My point is once the value will get update one from future, calling setState will refresh the ui and widget will be updated based on `islogin`

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked on the real device

Comment: Glad to help, you can find more about [`FutureBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html)